# AWS S3 getObject JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using JS SDK 2.7.13 for AWS. I can not seem to getObject from S3 using a web browser.

i tried the code listed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)

```
getS3Object(){

    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

    AWS.config.update({
        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
              IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
        })
    });
    AWS.config.credentials.refresh(function(){

        let s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-east-1', params: {Bucket: 'BUCKET NAME'}});
        let params = {
            Bucket: 'BUCKET NAME',
            Key: "NAME OF FILE I WANT"
        };

        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
    });
}
```

I get

```
Error: Missing credentials in config
```

and

```
"NotAuthorizedException: Missing credentials in config
```

i can get the item if i use the url path but i also want to upload later on so i would need this to work.

Comment: This example worked perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308859/3502144

Comment: Do you want unauthenticated access? because this method is giving credentials for unauthenticated users access to your AWS resources. If that is the case then make sure you have unauthenticated access enabled in your Cognito identity pool and assigned a proper role for that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to get temporary access credentials from [AWS cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html) and update `AWS.config.credentials`. Refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) link for more details.

Comment: How would this work with cognito http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-federated-id.html this is to get temp creds